# Linux user group configuration for Git bare repository

Tags: linux, permissions, git, groups

I'm using a Ubuntu box to host my bare Git repositories for developers to work off.

At the moment I'm creating a user account for each developer on the box because it doubles as a filestore and local testing server.

When somebody pushes to the bare repository other developers are unable to work on the files which change in the objects folder as a result.  The new files are created with the user of the developer who pushes.

I have placed all the developers into a dev group but the umask doesn't allow the group to edit.

I've never had to set up a Git repository so haven't had experience in working with the permissions.  I do want each developer to have their own user account on the test server, and I would prefer them to do actions on the server using that account.  I don't mind giving them sudo rights.

Is setting the umask for each developer the way forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While "[How do I share a Git repository with multiple users on a machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine)" does address your issue (and involves setting `umask` for the users), I prefer adding to my git installation an authorization layer like **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** (see [its documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/)).

- No sudo right to give to anymone.
- All git repo operations are done by one '`git`' user.
- you can set precisely the `umask` for newly created (and gitolite-managed) Git repos: "[Setting `umask` in Git / Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086325/setting-umask-in-git-gitolite/7103499#7103499)"

Answer (score 6):

Make a common group, e.g. `gitusers` and add all developers to this group.

```
chown -R root:gitusers /path/to/repository.git
chmod 2775 /path/to/repository.git
```

You might need to change permissions recursively, e.g.:

```
find /path/to/repository.git -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /path/to/repository.git -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
```

Now all your developers should have write access to the repository.